# Should I use an enum as a template parameter just for specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to remove code duplication. I have two classes that do pretty much the same thing but for different types.

I therefore created a class template depending on the type of a member and added trait classes to look up the corresponding type of another member.

Now I just discovered that for one of my types there is an enum member that is used to call different functions in one or two places.

So my traits struct doesn't work anymore because its template argument is the type of the member but now I need two different specializations depending on another member.

Summarily I now have three set of code that do mostly the same thing which I could refactor using templates but there is no type to base the specializations on.

Should I create an enum for the three types and use that as template parameter or is there a different canonical solution?

**Edit**: Code example! It turned out to be very long but I wanted something that compiles.

```
// original state

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Foo {
public:
  std::string GetFooAttributes() {
    return "<Foo attributes>";
  }
};

class Bar {
public:
  std::string GetSomeAttributes() {
    return "<Some Bar attributes>";
  }
  std::string GetOtherAttributes() {
    return "<Other Bar attributes>";
  }
};

enum BarAttrType { SomeBarAttrs, OtherBarAttrs };

class FooLogger {
  Foo mFoo;
public:
  FooLogger(Foo foo) : mFoo(foo) {};
  /* a lot of code */
  void log() {
    std::cout << mFoo.GetFooAttributes() << std::endl;
  }
};

class BarLogger {
  Bar mBar;
  BarAttrType mAttrType;
public:
  BarLogger(Bar bar, BarAttrType attrType) : mBar(bar), mAttrType(attrType) {};
  /* a lot of code that looks pretty much like in FooLogger */
  void log() {
    if(mAttrType) {
      std::cout << mBar.GetOtherAttributes() << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << mBar.GetSomeAttributes() << std::endl;
    }
  }
};





// current template solution

template <typename LOGOBJECT>
std::string GetAttributesHelper(LOGOBJECT logObject) {};

template <>
std::string GetAttributesHelper<Foo>(Foo foo) {
  return foo.GetFooAttributes();
}

template <>
std::string GetAttributesHelper<Bar>(Bar bar) {
  return bar.GetSomeAttributes();
  /* return bar.GetOtherAttributes ...sometimes */
}



template <typename LOGOBJECT>
class Logger {
  LOGOBJECT mLogObject;
public:
  Logger(LOGOBJECT logObject) : mLogObject(logObject) {};
  /* other code that is pretty similar in all cases */
  void log() {
    std::cout << GetAttributesHelper(mLogObject) << std::endl;
  }
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Foo myFoo;
  Bar myBar;

  // old solution
  FooLogger fooLogger(myFoo);
  fooLogger.log();
  BarLogger someBarLogger(myBar, SomeBarAttrs);
  someBarLogger.log();
  BarLogger otherBarLogger(myBar, OtherBarAttrs);
  otherBarLogger.log();

  // new solution
  Logger<Foo> tFooLogger(myFoo);
  tFooLogger.log();
  Logger<Bar> tSomeBarLogger(myBar);
  tSomeBarLogger.log();
  //Logger<Bar> otherBarLogger(myBar, OtherBarAttrs); // PROBLEM!
  //otherBarLogger.log();


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Care to provide some example code? That makes your issue much clearer than those descritions. However, it sounds like policies or CRTP could be what you are looking for - we'll need some code to confirm that, though.

Comment: Alright, give me a minute. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scenario in your example, you want to generate a function `log()` which calls a specific member-function of the object that is the first template-parameter.

You can achieve this by adding a non-type template-parameter which contains the pointer to the member function you want to call.

```
template <typename T, std::string(T::*getAttributes)()>
class Logger {
  T mLogObject;
public:
  Logger(T logObject) : mLogObject(logObject) {};
  void log() {
    std::cout << (mLogObject.*getAttributes)() << std::endl;
  }
};
```

The syntax for declaring a member-pointer - seen in the second template-parameter:
`ReturnType (ObjectType::*memberPointer)(ArgumentTypes...)`.

The syntax for calling the member-function through the member-pointer - seen in the`log()` function:
`(object.*memberPointer)(arguments...)`

This is how you would take a pointer to the member-function and use it as a template argument:

```
  Foo myFoo;
  Bar myBar;

  Logger<Foo, &Foo::GetFooAttributes> tFooLogger(myFoo);
  tFooLogger.log();
  Logger<Bar, &Bar::GetSomeAttributes> tSomeBarLogger(myBar);
  tSomeBarLogger.log();
  Logger<Bar, &Bar::GetOtherAttributes> tOtherBarLogger(myBar);
  tOtherBarLogger.log();
```

Comment: As long as there is just one difference. If there are more, you'll need either policy (template argument is structure that has methods like `GetAttributes` (it may have `typedef` for the primary type and be the only argument or be separate argument)) or CRTP (base class template specialized to a class deriving it, which can than have any extra members or whatever).

Comment: @JanHudec Do you have links to more elaborate explanations of the first? CRTP I found on wikipedia.

Comment: @Sarien: There is nothing complicated on the first. It's similar to this answer, just instead of passing `&Foo::GetFooAttributes` you pass `FooAttributeGetter` which defines method `GetAttributes(Foo const &)`, so it can also define `GetSomethingElse(Foo const &)` etc.

Comment: @JanHudec So basically it is like a traits struct except without a template argument and instead of the template argument you pass the struct as template argument, correct?